# XML Schema for Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler

Tags: xml, oracle, xsd, oracle-sqldeveloper

Oracle Data Modeler uses xml as file format to save models.

Has anybody a clue, whether there is a xml schema available that these files confirm to?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you haven't done so already I would ask this question over on the OTN Sql Developer Data Modeler Forum http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=1317 as you are likely to get a response from one of the developers or the Product manager

Answer (score 1):

You could try looking in your system for this JAR file oracle.sqldeveloper.xmlschema.jar and see if the file is inside. Of course, the format could change between versions.